# McLust latent profile analysis results

Tags: r, clustering, interpretation, latent-class

I'm currently running a latent profile analysis with the McLust package in R. My aim is to see whether the program is able to distinguish different profiles based on various (n=11) neuropsychological tests. The dataset `x` contains 279 participants, and all the data is -transformed. This dataset is imported into R, and then the following commands are run:

```
BIC <- mclustBIC(x, G=1:9)

plot(BIC)

summary(BIC)
```

[image: Results of LPA analysis]

All goes well and the results show that the best fit, is a model with a single profile. Although this is not what we expect, this is not necessarily an indication that something is wrong. I’m puzzled because when I look at the plot, there seems to be a big discrepancy between various mcLustModels.

Could someone inform me about, why there is such a big discrepancy and whether it is a problem? Should I conclude that there is only one profile?

Comment: So i figured out that i forgot to recode one of my variables (for all variable but for this one, a higher score indicates better performance). I recoded the variable en rerun the analysis. I now have four profiles :)!

Comment: McLust sounds like a fast food porn site. Are you sure you got the package name right?